# Firebase Javascript: Get id of the first child

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the id of the first child in my database, but it returns "undefined". Below is my code, and how my data is structured:

```
var database = firebase.database().ref();
var postsRef = database.child("posts");
postsRef.orderByChild("date").limitToFirst(1).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.ref.parent);
});
```

And this is how my data is structured:

```
posts
    1
        date
        title
        alias
        timestamp
    2
        date
        title
        alias
        timestamp
    3
        date
        title
        alias
        timestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var postsRef = database.child("posts");
postsRef.orderByChild("date").limitToFirst(1).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#limitToFirst
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#key

Comment: This gives me "post", not the id (1, 2, 3)

Comment: Are you sure that your data is structured the same way as in your OP then? Or is there a post with the id "key"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var snapshotKey = snapshot.key;
var snapshotData = snapshot.val();
```